# pandas json object read error when using flask request get_json

Tags: json, pandas, flask

I am passing a JSON object through a POST API into a flask app. The goal is to convert it to a single row pandas DF and pass it on for further processing.

the JSON payload is as follows:

```
{
  "ABC": "123",
  "DATE": "2020-01-01",
  "AMOUNT": "100",
  "IDENTIFIER": "12345"
}
```

The output of `data=flask.request.get_json()`  and `print(data)` is

```
{'ABC': '123', 'DATE': '2020-01-01', 'AMOUNT': '100','IDENTIFIER': '12345'}
```

But when I do a `pd.read_json(data)` on it I get an error
`ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>`
Any ideas on how to handle this? I need the output to be

```
ABC    DATE        AMOUNT    IDENTIFIER
123   2020-01-01   100        12345
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([data.values()], columns=data.keys())
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     ABC       DATE          AMOUNT   IDENTIFIER
 0   123       2020-01-01    100      12345
```